# Filter NSArray of NSDictionary , where the dictionary is of type <key , NSDictionary>

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have a NSArray like this

> [ {
>       "268" :   { "name" : "abc", "age" : "28"} }, {
>       "267" :    { "name" : "xyz","age" : "25"} } ]

Now I want to filter it on behalf of keys (means 268 , 267 ).
 Eg : If user search for 7 then it need to show

> [ {  "267" :    { "name" : "xyz","age" : "25"} } ]

Comment: An array of dictionaries with one key-value pair respectively is a pretty inefficient model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let filterText : String = "7"

let array : [Dictionary<String,Any>] = [ ["268" : [ "name" : "abc", "age" : "28"]], [ "267" : [ "name" : "xyz","age" : "25"] ] ]

let result = array.filter { (dictinory) -> Bool in
    if let firstKey = dictinory.keys.first {
            return firstKey.contains(filterText)
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSPredicate with block in Objective-C to filter it:

```
  NSString *searchText = @"8";
  NSArray *data = @[@{ @"268" : @{ @"name" : @"abc", @"age" : @"28"} }, @{ @"267" : @{ @"name" : @"xyz",@"age" : @"25"}}];
  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock: ^BOOL(id obj, NSDictionary *bind) {
    NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *)obj;
    NSString *key = dict.allKeys.firstObject;
    return [key containsString:searchText];
  }];
  NSArray *filteredData = [data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```